Singular or plural nouns after "with"

Perform daily inspections on machines with a start button(/with start buttons).
Vehicles with a third row(/with third rows)
Install an e-stop push button (/push buttons) on machines equipped with a cleaning system(/cleaning systems).

In the sentences using "with" like the above, should I use singular or plural nouns before and after with? I have seen many sentences using both so I am confused. (Regarding the third sentence what I want to say is that one button for one machine having a cleaning system)

In daily conversation they're synonymous, and even though a car will usually have only one catalytic converter, you can say "This law applies to cars with catalytic converters" and still be grammatical and understood.  A lawyer might rephrase it to "This law applies to any vehicle that has been fitted with a catalytic converter."  You can use the singular and install a button on machines even though a single button cannot be installed on multiple machines. People know that it means "on each machine a certain type of button".

Note: You might not want to use the plural in any case where it might be mistaken for, e.g., "multiple start buttons per machine." In these examples it's pretty clear, but some other situation might not be. Also, the plurals only work because the other noun is plural. You can't say "Perform inspections on every machine with start buttons."

Thank you. So I should just use either way depends on the situation? and there are no definite rule?


"machines with a start button" would mean any machine with at least one start button
"machines with start buttons" could mean machines with multiple start buttons.

Consider the description "persons with hands". Would you think that description applied to persons who, for whatever reason, only had one hand? The fact it specificities hands in the plural could arguably exclude them.
In practical use, most people would not think too deeply about the difference between these, but in some situations it is vitally important to eliminate any ambiguity. For example if a hospital said "all our wards have emergency exits" instead of "an emergency exit" that could suggest they have more than one, and people could be looking for an exit that doesn't exist in an emergency.

People could be looking for an exit that doesn't exist Do people really do that in real life (as opposed to Language World?)  Like the bloke who drowned because no-one would save him?

Thank you. For the first one, why is it at least one start button instead of one start button?

@JiroF. Consider this - your friend asks you - "do you have a dollar?" and you have ten dollars in your pocket, do you answer "no"? Of course not. You have a dollar and more. So that's why, by default, it means at least one. If you are specifying that something must have only one you need to say so.

I got it!!Thank you!!
